# Calling a class in main

Tags: java, class, static, program-entry-point, public

Hi I seem to have a problem calling a class in a main. Can somebody point it out?

KilometerTabel.java

```
package pratikum31d;
public static double mijlToKilometer() {
    double mijl;
    mijl = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        mijl = i;
    }
    double kilometer = 1.609 * mijl;
    System.out.println(kilometer + " kilometer" + " dat is " + mijl + " mijl");
    return kilometer;
}
```

Main.java

```
package pratikum31d;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        kilometer = mijlToKilometer();

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you imported KilometerTabel?

Comment: the importing part shouldnt be of importance cuz I already have this: package pratikum31d; at the first line of both java files

Comment: Please edit your post and explain what the problem is you're having. "I seem to be having a problem" without stating what the problem is you're having is meaningless; it's like calling your doctor on the phone and saying "I hurt right here. What could be wrong?". Without more information (including where "right here" is), you're not going to get an answer. Any time you type "I get an error" or "I have a problem", you need to follow that immediately with what the error or problem is, including any error messages you're receiving. Writing better questions leads to better chances of an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

You never defined a variable called `mijl` in `main`.  What value do you expect to get passed to `mijlToKilometer`?

===UPDATE ===

Your new code will have the following problems:

`mijlToKilometer` is still declared to expect an argument, so you won't be able to call it with no arguments.  You must remove the `double mijl` from the definition of `mijlToKilometer`.

Your `for` loop doesn't do what you think it does, though I'm having a hard time identifying what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Hi I added "double mijl;" right above the double kilometer......And it says now: variable mijl might not have been initialized

Comment: @AndrewNg: That's because you haven't initialized it. What value to do you want `mijl` to have?

Comment: Variable "mijl" might not have been initialized. Have you initialized it? Else poor variable won't know its value when it's passed to the method.

Comment: @ruakh The value should be the i generated within the for loop in KilometerTabel.java

Comment: @AndrewNg: Oh, I see. The problem is that `mijlToKilometer()` shouldn't actually have a parameter at all.

Comment: @ruakh in the KilometerTabel.java class?

Comment: @ruakh Ok I did as you told me and modified the code a bit, I still can't think of a way to call it out in the main. Netbeans still gives me error in main.java. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post your modified code in an edit to your original question?

Comment: The 'i' will generate the numbers 1-10 and throws it in the calculation below. After that it will give the 10 results of the calculation

Comment: Ok update: I've removed the double mijl as you said. And I received an error, in which I added mijl = 0; And the error disappeared. Not sure if it's the correct way though.... X_X

Comment: @AndrewNg, I think you might need to review some very basic Java tutorials.  I can't address the full extent of your confusion here.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare mijlToKilometer as public.

```
public static double mijlToKilometer(double mijl)
```

Answer (score 0):

What are the packages for `KilometerTabel` and the main class? You haven't put any public/private/protected modifier before your static method. so by default, it will have `default` [visibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html). Which is visible within the package. make sure that you bave both classes in same package OR put a **public** keyword before methods.

secondly, can you please post exact exception?

Comment: Im sorry I don't quite follow you there. You see I'm just starting to write Java for school assignments so you really did seem to say something useful there but I still don't quite follow :p